# Calculate the next Inverse laplace transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

This question may be very basic, but I dont know how to get the next inverse laplace's transform:

$${\scr L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\right\}$$

I can only use these two formulas:
${\scr L}\{e^{at}\}=\frac{1}{(s-a)}$ and 
${\scr L}\{t^n\}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$

I can also use all the laplace's transform properties but the definition of the laplace transform definition

Comment: Can't you use anything else - for example, the frequency shift property of the Laplace transform (which follows just from the definition of the transform)?

Comment: @jkn I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition we have the phase shift,$$
F(s):={\scr L} \{ f(t) \}\implies {\scr L} \{ e^{at} f(t) \} = F(s-a)
$$

Therefore
$$
{\scr L}\{e^tt\}(s) = {\scr L}\{t\}(s-1) = \left\{\frac 1 {s^2}\right\}(s-1) = \frac 1 {(s-1)^2}
$$

Giving,

$$
{\scr L^{-1}}\left\{ \frac 1 {(s-1)^2} \right\} = e^tt
$$

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Both answers were right, but this one is the most complete.

Comment: @Alejandro, a pleasure. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Frequency shift property: If $\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=F(s)$ then $\mathcal{L}[e^{a t}f(t)]=F(s-a)$.

Try using it to evaluate $\mathcal{L}[e^{t}t]$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the property

$$\mathcal{L}[tf(t)] = -F'(s), $$

where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and the fact

$$ \mathcal{L}[e^{t}] = \frac{1}{(s-1)}  $$

the result follows.